# Invalid use of group function

Tags: база-данных, mysql

SELECT COUNT(`Value`) FROM (SELECT * FROM `***` AS t2
WHERE `Ygeo` > 0 AND DATEDIFF(`SpeedBeginDate`, CURDATE()) > 14 AND Sum(`Loss`) > 1000
GROUP BY HEX(`Hash1`)) AS t1;

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы используете агрегатную функцию `SUM` в конструкции `WHERE`. Этого делать нельзя. Для использования агрегатных функций в условии надо использовать [`HAVING`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(Value)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `***` AS t2
    WHERE
        Ygeo > 0 
        AND DATEDIFF(SpeedBeginDate, CURDATE()) > 14 
    GROUP BY
        HEX(Hash1)
    HAVING
        Sum(Loss) > 1000 
) AS t1;
```